# Can an angular attribute directive replace parent and child elements?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Can an angular attribute directive replace parent and child elements?

This is what I mean. Can i create one directive that will replace the 'parent-stylings' and 'child-stylings' below

```
<div class="parent-stylings">
    <div class="child-stylings"></div>
</div>
```

into something like this

```
<div #myCustomDirective></div>
```

Comment: To manipulate the DOM like you want you need to create a directive and use the renderer2. [checkthis](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/).   but still I think that you need to use <ng-template #myCustomeTemplate>your code..<ng-template> [someInfoAboutNgTemplate](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

Comment: @TheNsn666 way overkill IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to change the selector of a component. It's that easy.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[myCustomDirective]',
  template: `
<div class="parent-stylings">
    <div class="child-stylings"></div>
</div>`
}) export class MyComponent {}
```

[See it working live !](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skmjht)

Comment: I was actually looking for how to reuse a component using ng-content( I now know)... but I did not know how to word my question. But your answer answers my question the way it is asked. Thanks.

Comment: Component and Directives are different in Angular perpective...